# How to compute opposite view from a quaternion rotation?

Tags: math, graphics, rotation, quaternions

I have a quaternion rotation, as usually described by 4 values: `a b c d`.
Lets say it transforms the x axis so that i look at some object from the front. Now i want to change this rotation so i look at the object from the back. 
So basicly i want to change the viewpoint from front to back, but do that using this rotation.

How can the opposite rotation be computed?

Comment: Why do you want to do it by object rotation? If you'll do it with change of camera position and view vector it's much easier..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learning from the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation), it seems that if you want to perform a 180° rotation around the **z** axis, then the corresponding Quaternion rotation would simply be:

```
0 0 0 1
```

The key here is the formula [image], where (w,x,y,z) = (a,b,c,d).

Indeed, since cos(90°) = 0 and sin(90°) = 1, then replacing alpha with 180° and **u** with (0, 0, 1), gives you (0, 0, 0, 1).

**Edit**: As Christian has pointed out, the up direction need not be **z**, but may be any *unit* vector **u** = (x,y,z) (otherwise normalize it by dividing by its norm). In that case, the corresponding 180° quaterion rotation would be

```
0 x y z
```

Now to apply this rotation in order to move around the object, say you have the position an the direction vetors of your camera `c_pos` and `c_dir`, then simply (left) conjugate it by `q = (0 x y z)`, and move the camera position accordingly. Something like

```
c_dir = q * c_dir * q^-1
c_pos = 2 * o_pos - c_pos
```

where `o_pos` is the position of the object, and `c_dir` should be converted to a quaternion with 0 real part.

Comment: The axis to rotate around is the up-axis of his camera/object, which need not be the z-axis but is defined by him. Otherwise good answer.

Comment: Also, to get my vote, you'd need to explain how to apply this rotation to his current quaternion.  And I second what @Christian Rau said. :)

Answer (score -2):

In my case, hel me this..

original quat                 (x  y  z  w)
opposite oriented quat        (y -x  w -z)